Apollo client returning Unknown Type Error when executing a mutation
I've got a problem with running my graphql mutation due to the following error:
"errors": [
        {
            "message": "Unknown type \"GenderInput\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 37
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
                "stacktrace": [
                    "GraphQLError: Unknown type \"GenderInput\".",`

I have not had this problem until I have created a custom input type, GenderInput.
This is my frontend mutation:
export const CALCULATE_CALORIES = gql`
  mutation calculateCalories(
    $gender: GenderInput!
    $weight: String!
    $activityLevel: Float!
    $goal: GoalInput!
    $user_id: String!
  ) {
    calculateCalories(
      gender: $gender
      weight: $weight
      activityLevel: $activityLevel
      goal: $goal
      user_id: $user_id
    )
  }
`;

and this is my TypeDefinitions File in the Backend. From the schema I've provided, it seems to me that GenderInput is defined correctly but i still get this error. I have tried restarting Apollo server but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.
export const typeDefsWorkout = `#graphql

type exercise {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    muscletrained: String
    user_id: String!
  }

  type component {
  component_id: ID!
  repetitions: Int!
  sets: Int!
  exercise_id: ID!
 }

 type userComponent {
  component_id: ID!
  repetitions: Int!
  sets: Int!
  exercise_id: ID!
  user_id: String!
 }

 type WorkoutComponent {
  component_id: ID!
  repetitions: Int!
  sets: Int!
  name: String!
}
type WorkoutComponents {
  component_id: ID!
  repetitions: Int!
  sets: Int!
  name: String!
}
type User{
  user_id: ID!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  first_name: String!
  last_name: String!
}
input GenderInput{
  label: String!
  value: String!
}
input GoalInput{
  label: String!
  value: String!
}
type Goal{
  label: ID!
  goal: String!
  }

  type Query {
    exerciseComponents: [WorkoutComponent!]!
    exerciseComponentsUser(user_id: String!): [WorkoutComponent]!
    userExercises(user_id: String!): [exercise]!
    exercises: [exercise!]!
    exercise(id: ID!): exercise
    login(email: String!, password: String!): User
    getGoals: [Goal!]!
  }

  type Mutation {
    createUser(email: String!, password: String!, first_name: String!, last_name: String!): User!
    calculateCalories(gender: GenderInput!, weight: String!, activityLevel: Float!, goal: GoalInput!, user_id: String!): Float!
    createExercise(name: String!, muscletrained: String!, user_id: String!): exercise!
    deleteExercise(id: ID!): ID
    deleteComponent(component_id: ID!): ID
    createComponent(repetitions: Int!, sets: Int!, exercise_id: ID!): component!
    createComponentUser(repetitions: Int!, sets: Int!, exercise_id: ID!, user_id: String!): userComponent!
    deleteComponentUser(component_id: ID!): ID
  }
`;

Everything worked fine until i made a custom type as the input (GenderInput). Any help would be appreciated.

In my case, I try to remove the backend ValidationPipe and it works for me.
  async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: true,
  });
  // app.useGlobalPipes(
  //   new ValidationPipe({
  //     whitelist: true,
  //     forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
  //     transform: true,
  //   }),
  // );
  await app.listen(app.get(ConfigService).get('port'));
}
bootstrap();

Hope this can help you!
